# Strophe.js Notification Received (Composing)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmpp, strophe

I am trying to get notified when typing.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/strophe.min.js"></script>
```

---

```
connection.addHandler(onNotificationReceived, null, "message", "chat", null,  null);
```

---

```
function onNotificationReceived(msg)
{

    var composing = $(msg).find('composing'),
        paused = $(msg).find('paused'),
        active = $(msg).find('active'),
        jid = $(msg).attr('from');

        if (composing.length > 0)
        {
            $('.chat-feedback').css('display', 'block');
            alert(1);
        }

        if (paused.length > 0)
        {
            $('.chat-feedback').css('display', 'none');
            alert(2);
        }

        if (active.length > 0)
        {
            $('.chat-feedback').css('display', 'none');
            alert(3);
        }

    return true;
}
```

But it does not work :(

Please help!

---

PS.
Сomplete script http://sitechat.ru/tests/chat1/

Comment: Where are you building the connection? You seem to be missing a lot of things here, can you show the complete script?

Comment: Debug your handler in the borwser. Or put console.log() on after every line in the handler. For example: console.log('composing = ' + composing); etc.

Comment: @Spokey What is missing? Messages are sent and received. The interviewee is notified typing chat with. But to get notification of typing does not work.

Comment: @UlukBiy Biy, I've tried. Empty

Comment: @AlexV show the msg content received.

Comment: @UlukBiy  <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><message xmlns='jabber:client' type='chat' to='24776d11@kirova.dorogobid.com/24776d11' id='qip_139' from='test2@kirova.dorogobid.com/QIP'><body> test message</body></message></body>

Comment: @Spokey complete script http://sitechat.ru/tests/chat1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the response as XML in `onNotificationReceived(msg)`

```
var msg = $.parseXML(msg);
```

And I think you meant

```
jid = $(msg).find('message').attr('from');
```

Comment: Oh, no. 
Notification did not come, only messages